# How to show three elements in a row while iterating through a list of elements in angular7?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular7

In Angular, from a list of items I need to show n elements in a row.

I have pasted the code from Angular on what I tried but not able to repeat the `<tr>` tags.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0 table-hover">
  <tbody *ngFor="let tableColObj of LWTableColumnNames.refLWTableColumnNames; let i=index">
    <tr>
      <td *ngIf="tableColObj.SelectionFlag == true">{{tableColObj.COLUMN_NAME}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
List - [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6]

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>e1</td>
    <td>e2</td>
    <td>e3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e4</td>
    <td>e5</td>
    <td>e6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much easier to make an array that meets your needs rather that having complex templates.

```js
const data = ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6'];

const group = (array, groupSize) => array.reduce((results, current, index) => {
  if (index % groupSize === 0) {
    results.push([current]);
  } else {
    results[results.length - 1].push(current);
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(group(data, 3));
```

Now you can have a loop for rows, and a loop inside for cells.

Comment: produceSubArrayResults(results=[],  array, groupSize ) {
        for ( var index = 0; index < array.length; index++ ) {
            if ( index % groupSize === 0 ) {
                results.push( [ array[index]] );
            } else {
                results[results.length - 1].push( array[index] );
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
    console.log( this.produceSubArrayResults(this.results, this.LWcolumnNamesJson, 3))

Comment: Simplified code? You took a reduce function and made a for loop that mutates an input.

Comment: I mean, to understand a fresher. I took a lot of time to understatnd it. thats why